# Can SQL test by using SqlMap tool harm a website?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I am just learning about SQL injection attack, and I want to test this by using sqlmap on my own website.However I wonder if the attack can cause any harm on my website's services during the attack? Thank you.

Comment: Never test a live system if you can avoid it.

Comment: thank you but I believe , if I do not try it on a live system , I can not observe how my website reacts  the sql attack.

Comment: Clone the system and try it on the clone.

Comment: thank you for the good advices , I will consider to clone my website . However I also wonder what are the possible bad results after an SQL attack with sqlmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could corrupt or destroy all the data on the system.

**Never try this on a live system**. Clone one or build one in order to test.